# Odoo 16 Float Field default value

Tags: odoo, field, floating, odoo-16

I have a Float field:

```
    ​field_name = fields.Float(string='The percentage paid upon signing the contract', default=6.7)
```

When I apply this, it shown as 670

same for default=50.0       ---> 5000

25.5 ---> 2550

I want to show the default value as 6.7 and 50.0 and 25.5

How could I do this .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `digits` attribute to your field definition:

```py
field_name = fields.Float(string='percentage paid...', default=6.7, digits=[1, 1])
```

and check if you use a widget in xml too.